# create polygon button with css

Tags: html, css

[image]

I wish to create the above button with only css
However, the button text i cannot move upward align with the button.
Any idea?

```css
body {
  padding: 100px;
}

a {
  border-top: 50px solid red !important;
  border-left: 25px solid transparent !important;
  border-right: 25px solid transparent !important;
  height: 0;
  width: 150px;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Read More</a>
```

https://codepen.io/w3nta1/pen/aRMEzK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you have the border on the top.
Here's a working example:

```css
body { padding:100px; }
a { 
    width: 200px;
 font-size: 14px; 
 letter-spacing: 1px; 
 color:#000; 
 text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration:none;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

a:before {
  content: "";
  border-top: 50px solid red !important;
  border-left: 25px solid transparent !important;
  border-right: 25px solid transparent !important;
  width: 150px;
  position:absolute;
}

span {
  z-index: 10;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><span>Read More</span></a>
```

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

There is solution without using `flex`, `table`, ... for `display`

```css
body { padding:50px; }
a { 
   border-top: 50px solid red !important;
    border-left: 25px solid transparent !important;
    border-right: 25px solid transparent !important;
    height: 0;
    width: 150px;
   font-size: 14px; 
   letter-spacing: 1px; 
   color:#000; 
   text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration:none;
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
}
a span {
  position:absolute;
  left:0; right:0;
  top:-50px;
  height:50px;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:50px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><span>Read More</span></a>
<a href="#"><span>About</span></a>
```

Into css for `a` add `position:relative; display:inline-block;`.
Since, `a` is height of 50px, "under" `a` add `span` element.

`span` will be positioning/filled into `a` using `position:absolute` and `top:0; let:0; right:0`, but, instead `bottom:0` I use `height:50px;` (from Your css for `a` `border-top: 50px solid red !important;`). At the end, align text into center (`text-align:center;`) and use `line-height:50px;` for vertically centering text.

Using this way You'll use basic css. This will work event on IE7.

Answer (score 0):

Here is more Simple One. Play with some paddings if you don't like this one.
For More shapes, check this [link](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/).

```css
body { padding: 100px; }

a{
  color: white;
  background: red;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 90% 100%, 10% 100%);
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Hello World</a>
```

Comment: Did You see browser support for `clip-path`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path

Comment: A better site to see the browser compatibility would be https://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path

Comment: Didn't check that before, thanks for letting me now.

Comment: Thanks. This seems easier. I prefer this one :)